# Bootstrap Dropdowns working Intermittently with Rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

I'm working on a Rails application with a persistent navigation bar including bootstrap dropdowns. For whatever reason it's working sporadically; on launch or refresh the dropdowns will always work, after the first redirect they will never work, and after that it seems to essentially alternate between working and not working. When it doesn't work, simply nothing happens when the dropdown is clicked. My initial suspicion was that Turbolinks was to blame, <s>but I haven't</s> *and I have* been able to verify this (see edit below). After spending a few hours reading up, I've tried all the "obvious" fixes I could find, with no luck as of yet.

It is worth noting that the problem persists...

- with or without turbolinks.jquery
- with bootstrap OR bootstrap-sprockets
- across all recent version of the bootstrap-sass gem
- whether or not a rearrange my application.js file
- with application.js data-turbolinks-track set to true OR false
- whether in development OR production

### EDITED:

*By disabling Turbolinks completely (removing the turboling and jquery-turbolinks gems, removing references to them both in application.js, and removing the data-turbolinks-track attributes in application.html.erb), I no have working dropdowns. That said, I would still like to know why this is not working, as I am hoping to re-enable turbolinks prior to release. /end-of-edit*

These are the files I believe to be relevant:

**application.js**

Note that //= require tree . is not present. This is deliberate (I have a number of page-specific javascripts, and I include them with yields into the application.html.erb).

```js
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

**Gemfile.rb**

```rb
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.0'

# Bootstrap
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.4.1'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Make Turbolinks play nice with JQuery
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'

# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Gems for interfacing with SQL Server
gem 'tiny_tds'
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter'

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'


group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Test DB
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

**application.css.scss**

(just to prove that I included the other parts of bootstrap effectively)

```scss
/* CHARSET
-------------------------------------------------- */
@charset "utf-8";


/* IMPORTS - BOOTSTRAP
-------------------------------------------------- */
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";


/* IMPORTS - SCSS MIXINS
-------------------------------------------------- */
@import "mixins/*";


/* IMPORTS - LAYOUT CSS
-------------------------------------------------- */
@import "layout";


/* IMPORTS - CONTROLLERS' CSS
-------------------------------------------------- */
@import "controllers/*";
```

**application.html.erb**

Note that there are two different possible navigation bars (one when logged in, the other when logged out) that render from partials. Only the _nav_logged_in.html.erb contains drop downs, and I'll include that next.

Also note that all javascript loads are at the bottom of the file.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="This is APO Lite in the context of Ruby on Rails">
    <meta name="author" content="Connor McKee">
    <title>APO Lite</title>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body role="document">

<!-- Fixed navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <%= link_to "APO Lite", root_url, id: "navLogo", class: "navbar-brand" %>
        </div>


        <% if logged_in? %>
            <%= render 'layouts/nav_logged_in' %>
        <% else %>
            <%= render 'layouts/nav_logged_out' %>
        <% end %>

        <!--/.nav-collapse --> 
    </div>
</nav>

<header class="jumbotron subhead <%= 'expandedJumbotron' if current_page? root_url %>" id="overview">
  <div class="container">
    <% if has_project? && !current_page?( root_url ) %>
        <h1><%= current_project.name %></h1>
        <p class="lead"><%= current_project.description %></p>
    <% else %>
        <h1>WELCOME TO APO LITE</h1>
        <p class="lead">Your Journey towards a Better Project Management Experience Starts Here</p>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</header>

<div class="container">

    <!-- Page Description a.k.a. "Context" -->
    <% if content_for?(:context) %>
        <div class="row" id="context">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <%= yield :context %>
            </div>
        </div>
    <% end %>

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <%= yield %>

    <!-- This is debug info -->
    <% if Rails.env.development? %>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <%= debug(params) %>
            </div>
        </div>
    <% end %>

</div>


<!-- Javascripts -->
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<% if content_for?(:page_js) %>
    <%= yield :page_js %>
<% end %>

</body>
</html>
```

**_nav_logged_in.html.erb**

At last, here are the dropdowns themselves.

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
            <% if has_project? %>
                <%= link_to current_project.name, current_project %>
            <% else %>
                <a href="#about">My Project Name</a>
            <% end %>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Administer<span class="caret"></span></a><!--class="active"-->
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Questionnaires</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Support<span class="caret"></span></a><!--class="active"-->
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Documentation</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Help Desk</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><%= link_to "Log out", logout_path, method: "delete" %></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><%= current_user.first_name %><span class="caret"></span></a><!--class="active"-->
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><%= link_to "My Profile", current_user %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Log out", logout_path, method: "delete" %></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

**And finally, here is how the scripts are loaded when the application is running**

This is with bootstrap-sprockets, but bootstrap by itself causes the same problems. Please observe the lack of duplication anywhere.

```html
<!-- Javascripts -->
<script src="/assets/jquery.self-d03a5518f45df77341bdbe6201ba3bfa547ebba8ed64f0ea56bfa5f96ea7c074.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="false"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.self-8e98a7a072a6cee1372d19fff9ff3e6aa1e39a37d89d6f06861637d061113ee7.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="false"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.turbolinks.self-176b9819f30444d441e820bbccd3264fe57753aeafd54dec732b0dbc77129a2a.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="false"></script>
<script src="/assets/turbolinks.self-c37727e9bd6b2735da5c311aa83fead54ed0be6cc8bd9a65309e9c5abe2cbfff.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="false"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/affix.self-68d1a5161d04ca9fe1b9d9f4114d9426c7798bf90f2703a97aca35c8113469bb.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="false"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/alert.self-15ce09eba576e56db3edfd87accc0ff48823df915169e350b4fd97290f96aee1.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="false"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/button.self-37c62bff1d75f86f3348b8679873d5156d8b9938b62841038dca21690f4740f1.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="false"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/carousel.self-9aaab1a477b9c1156bab751cb8da47f77dace6da88eef8ae830e60f3cff3a8be.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="false"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/collapse.self-eeece00cd06a3d7cc071ab7845b549d4991edd0f0895e4be70fe40bac2fb5f4b.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="false"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/dropdown.self-a3998e7ca949c04cb86b5c635deb0abcc7a24dc02e81be66b8acfef02d811e45.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="false"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/modal.self-f2759e138605770e60526c00c6d86cbb3378da203641f9d6b204c9f0192b9267.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="false"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/scrollspy.self-5ea180afe4404f83fc97d997833f2edefd34475b0b5ddab310e27abc2bbd5f2f.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="false"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/tab.self-e1bba7115c90301056ee94c4716de2fcbe4498015def2dab9ff9879f339bd245.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="false"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/transition.self-7742dca5e6acf313fbb217811b48468282cddf1a9baea5c89ec92e367ef242cb.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="false"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/tooltip.self-c3b5c16f394ab9c0391db4431aac4f2d2ddf1bba4c5d3228ed343de05ecc8e83.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="false"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/popover.self-2674d99c3ab0415dba0b958a80b3840f70ff6368b155d890306c0291be49453b.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="false"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-sprockets.self-fbfa5ad7d9aa0afe439ec4ff3883acc4cb92b62cb67c40d674320c9aa1d4642d.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="false"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.self-f98a0dd27ad1c55b2b9cfe97296d4887e5d4a4535b3bbbf9130c1050771738b2.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="false"></script>
```

Comment: Did you used the JS debug tools of your browser?  The console may give you relevant JS errors. (F12 in Chrome Ctrl-Shift-K in FF)

Comment: Yes, I have in Chrome, and I have not found any errors. It appears I was correct about it being a problem with Turbolinks; I disabled the entire gem and things function properly now. I still want to have Turbolinks in the application, but I am updating the question accordingly.

Comment: I am having the same issue. By same, I mean same same. First entry work, navigate to another page via link then it stops working, then navigate to another page then it works again and on and on.
By any chance did u figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that jquery.turbolinks must be loaded before jquery_ujs.

Try this in your application.js file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

**Revision | removed extraneous load logs**

**Revision | added**

I don't think you should have a container div in the middle of your nav block. You might want to try copy / paste just this simple example structure (from a working app).

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav  pull-right">

      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          Dropdown <b class="caret"></b>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><%= link_to "A", some_working_url %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "A", some_working_url %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "A", some_working_url %></li>

        </ul>
      </li>
    </li>
     ...
   </ul>
```

Comment: That's actually how it was when I first identified the problem (and I just tested again to make sure I wasn't going crazy). Sadly, I've tried scrambling the requirements in every way, and no sequence worked.

Comment: I was just about to uplaod my  page source on load. I have this working,. I've had issues with jquery_ujs and turbolinks causing intermittent issues, but it's solvable, for sure.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I can confirm that the div is not the problem because I have a separate rails app running with [This Header](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVVNdw), in which the dropdowns work perfectly (note, that's just the relevant html; it seems like a misuse of CodePen, but I wouldn't paste that into a comment). I've actually had everything working correctly once before, I just can't find any observable difference.

Comment: Fair enough. So, what changed between working drop downs and intermittently working dropdowns?

Comment: Haha, that's  the question (they're two distinct projects, that happen to have similar headers). I'm trying to track down if this is related to rendering the dropdowns in a partial with turbolinks -- that's the only real difference I can identify (and it would make sense that this could change how the javascripts are loaded).

Comment: So ,one project uses turbolinks and the other, no? Turbolinks can reveal underlying problems; my experience has been that there is an underlying code/ setup problem that Turbolinks uncovers. But you may have something different going on. It seems to me it's going to require you to go into the browser dev tools and start setting breakpoints to see what's really happening.

Comment: Nope, they both use the same technology stack (including TurboLinks), which is why this is so perplexing. I know the problem involves Turbolinks, I just haven't been able to identify what difference between the two applications is causing this problem. But you are likely correct, and I'll keep hunting it down.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first understand why this happens. When turbolinks is enabled and you click on a link, a `page:change` event is fired and all javascript is re-evaluated from the newly loaded html.

This includes the bootstrap javascript code that's loaded within `application.js`. When bootstrap's javascript is reloaded, it breaks. You can fix this by using `data-turbolinks-eval=false` in the application.js `<script>` tag.

**Usage:**

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-eval' => false %>
<%= javascript_include_tag params[:controller] %>
```

Answer (score -1):

I used to have the same issue, "dropdown" only works the first time. I found out that I redirected "post request" to "get request" route. That's why it gets bootstrap not working properly. So I cancel the "redirect" to isolate "post request" and "get request".

Hope it helps.